# Java: JLabel not getting added on JFrame

Tags: java

Why am I not getting the label on the screen. This is my code :

```
class Guide extends JComponent {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Guide guide = new Guide();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong Game's Guide");
            frame.add(guide);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setSize(600,500);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setResizable(false);

            JLabel guideLabel = new JLabel();
            guideLabel.setText("GUIDE");
            guideLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 20));
            guideLabel.setForeground(new Color(255,0,0));
            guideLabel.setBounds(290,25,50,20);        
            frame.add(guideLabel);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(new Color(150,255,150));
            g.fillRect(0,0,690,590);        
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Comment: You have to add the `JLabel` to the frame first and then pack it and set visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You’ve made the window visible before adding the label. You will need to `revalidate` and `repaint` the container
2. `JFrame` by default uses a `BorderLayout`, which by default only allows a single component to be laid out in each of 5 available positions, which likely to cause issues. Probably better to add it to `guide`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the label to the frame, then setting the visibility of the frame to true.